# I want to change the appbar's title of the pages with respect to the curved navigation bar's tab

Tags: android, flutter, title, navigationbar, flutter-appbar

I am implementing curved navigation bar in my flutter project. But I can't recognise why the data is not passing to the second page(i.e. notification.dart page). The same data is showing in the first page(i.e. home.dart page) but not in the second page(i.e. notification.dart page)

Here is my code:

Appbar's code:

```
Widget aapBarSection(String title, Color color, BuildContext context){
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title, style:TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular'), ),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: color,
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Logout', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: () async{
            SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            preferences.setBool("isLogin", false);
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/login');
          },
        )
      ],
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: (){
          exit(0);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

NavigationBar's code:

```
int currentIndex = 0;
  Widget navBarSection(Color color, Color btnColor){
    return CurvedNavigationBar(
      index: 0,
      items:
      [
        Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white),
        Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.white),
        Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
        Icon(Icons.history, color: Colors.white),
        Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
      ],
      color: color,
      buttonBackgroundColor: btnColor,
      animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      onTap: (index){
        setState(() {
          currentIndex = index;
        });
      },
    );
  }


  void setState(Null Function() param0) {

  }
```

home.dart code:

```
import 'package:thehelpdesk/widgets/appbar.dart';
import 'package:thehelpdesk/widgets/navigation_bar.dart';
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: aapBarSection('Home',Colors.blueAccent[700],context),
      bottomNavigationBar: navBarSection(
        Colors.blueAccent[700],
        Colors.blueAccent[700],
    ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Text('abcd', style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 50,
            color: Colors.black
        ),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

notification.dart code:

```
import 'package:thehelpdesk/widgets/appbar.dart';
import 'package:thehelpdesk/widgets/navigation_bar.dart';

class NotificationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotificationPageState createState() => _NotificationPageState();
}

class _NotificationPageState extends State<NotificationPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: aapBarSection('Notification',Colors.blueAccent[700],context),
      bottomNavigationBar: navBarSection(
        Colors.blueAccent[700],
        Colors.blueAccent[700],
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Text('abcd', style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 50,
          color: Colors.black
        ),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you called your `HomePage` , `NotificationPage` in your navigation bar page?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede no I haven't. What's the need of that though ?

Comment: what does `w.r.t.` mean ? with regards to ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody with respect to

Comment: for a lot of people, English isn't their first (or even second) language, so it's usually best to avoid these abbreviations and acronyms when asking a question (development is hard enough already without trying to figure these out!), this counts for the workplace too, but it's just my personal opinion :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody sure I will take care of it